# How to get rid of #define of same macro in multiple files in a huge C++ code base?

Tags: c++, macros

I have a peculiar problem. I have a huge code base, and every file has a `#define LOGFILE` macro which is `undef`-ed at the end of the file. For example, `FileA.cpp` will have the macro defined as `#define LOG_COMPONENT [FileA]` , and so on. At the end of the file, this will be then removed by `#undef LOG_COMPONENT`, and this happens for every single file. It is obviously not a very good design, and SONAR is losing its head over this.

Edit : This `LOG_COMPONENT` macro is being passed to the internal logger object, that writes it to the log file. It's basically specifying which component the log originated from.

What would be the easiest way to convert this into a `constexpr`, or `const`? Or how do I make SONAR ignore this problem for all occurrences?

Comment: I once watched Damian Conway give a public speech. It's one of his regular speeches. It's the "You're a programmer, so write a frickin program" speech. So, what's stopping you from using C++, or any other language of your choice, from writing a simple program that reads each file, and writes out a new one, with the appropriate changes to its contents?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik probably a bit excessive in this case, a regex in a text editor is likely easier depending on what exactly needs changing

Comment: Sure, @AlanBirtles, but which text editors have a menu option to read every file in a directory hierarchy, and apply the regex to the contents of each file, and then save them?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik notepad++, vscode, visual studio, regexxer probably others

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't think they want to expand the macro, that would be an even worse design.

Comment: I don't see a big problem with the macro as it is now, but simply replacing this `#define` with `constexpr std::string_view` could work, depending on how the logging macros are written (and fixing them should be trivial).

Comment: What EXACTLY is sonar complaining about?